# input date serial number and preserve target format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I update a sheet with date serial numbers (e.g. 41615 for 07.12.2013). Then I format the column where the serial is so that it shows "07.12.2013".

I would like to update the sheet and preserve the format, I tried:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate`

with the following payload:
`{"valueInputOption":"RAW","data":<valueRange>,"includeValuesInResponse":false}`

but it does not work, it always overwrite the format. Is this actually possible ?

Comment: I think that in your case, for example, when the cell format of the column "A" is `dd\"/\"mm\"/\"yyyy` and the value of `41615` is put to the column "A" using "values.batchUpdate" with your request, the put value is shown as `07/12/2013`. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, when you use `USER_ENTERED` instead of `RAW`, what result will you get?

Comment: Just like @Tanaike has mentioned above, would you mind providing a sample spreadsheet for this as well?

Comment: do you mean I should grant you access to the google sheet ? actually it's pretty straightforward to replicate it : you format the column "A" as date (any format) then using the API you try to input e.g. 41615. If the format is preseved it should dsiplay 07.12.2013

Comment: Did you add any of these options to your request as well: `responseValueRenderOption` or `responseDateTimeRenderOption`? @laloune

Comment: good point. No I did not use the option `includeValuesInResponse` since I don't need this response